# How to manually pass a return url to Action asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an ecommerce mvc5 web application. I have an action "ListItem" where Users can list items to sell. I created a custom authorize attribute that checks if user is in seller role and if not redirects the user to a setup action where the user can register with company Name and taxId etc. to get added to the seller role.
Now that the user registered(and was added to seller role) I want to redirect the user to the "listItem action"(where the user can continue and list their item) via passing in a "return url" to the "Setup Action". I am not sure how this is achieved (I am fairly new to asp.net mvc) Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When redirecting to the `Setup` action, add a `returnUrl` to the failed authorization route data.

For example overriding the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` in `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
public sealed class CompanyMustBeRegisteredAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // or filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
        var returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
        filterContext.Result =
            new RedirectToActionResult("Setup", "SetupController", new { returnUrl });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! You saved the day. what worked was the "Request.RawUrl". For some reason the "Request.Url.ToString" didn't work for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to redirect the user to listItem action

Then why not use [`RedirectToAction()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) method like

```
return RedirectToAction(action, controller);
```

Comment: Because I am planning on using the setup action on other actions that requires that the user should be a seller.